# HTML5 FORM, AJAX VALIDATION

Tags: ajax, forms, html, jquery

I am trying to develop a HTML5 contact form, and validate it with jQuery / AJAX.

The only help I could find online is [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/build-a-neat-html5-powered-contact-form/), which explains how to do this in modern browsers for the new HTML5 form attributes (required and min-length), and with the use of polyfills for older browsers, though my needs are a little different.

Essentially, I want people to either request one of three checkboxes, or type in a message. Individually, none of these elements are required, but I want at least one of them to contain data before the form is submitted.

Can do this with PHP using something like:

```
if(empty ($checkbox1) && empty($checkbox2) && empty($checkbox3) && empty($message) ){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You need to either make a request for information, or ask a question.";
}
```

If anyone knows how this can be written for jQuery / AJAX it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you checked this : http://www.matiasmancini.com.ar/ajax-jquery-validation-html5-form.html

Comment: Can you provide the HTML of the form? You can post it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com)

Comment: Hey Nadav, the HTML of the form is exactly the same as that on the tutorial posted above, with the addition of three input checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If the information is stuff you don't want in a get request then look into the jQuery `$.post()` function.  The documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ should be plenty to get you along the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
     var $checkbx1 = $( '#checkbox1' ),
         $checkbx2 = $( '#checkbox2' ),
         $checkbx3 = $( '#checkbox3' ),
         formok = true,
         $msg = $( '#mymsg' ).val();
```

user tries to submit the form:

```
    $( '#submitBtn' ).click( function() {
        if( ( $checkbx1.val() == '' && $checkbx2.val() == '' &&
              $checkbx3.val() == '' ) || $msg == '' ) {

            formok = false;

        }

        if( formok )
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'yourUrl',
                data: 'yourData',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: cb <-- your callback function
            });
        }
    });
```